# Remove border around in-page link

Tags: html, css, border

I have links on my page which are internal, for example:

```
/page#h1
/page#h2
```

When you click on one of these links, in Chrome you see a blue border around the link like follows:

[image]

The additional space the border surrounds above the text is caused by the rule:

```
.jumpTarget:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  height:90px;
  margin:-90px 0 0;
}
```

Which compensates for a fixed position top horizontal menu.

How do I remove this blue border?  I've tried the CSS selector `:target` to specify a red border but this gives me:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must use style rule `.jumpTarget:active {outline:none;}`

Comment: Doesn't fix issue in Chrome, however with the selector `:target` it does work :)  If you update your answer I'll accept.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle